# Use a friedman.test on a data frame sorted with grep()

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been able to apply a friedman on my first df occ with several conditions of Var1 and two time (tps) conditions "Av" and "Ap". The subsetting of my df with grep works but, even if the data is well suited for a friedman (as before the grep operation) there is the same number of measures for each conditions, the test doesn't work and retturn 'this is not not an unreplicated complete block design'. I would like to know if the grep function modify something about the df that prevent from doing the test.

I have tried other methods of subseetting , using the library dplyr but couldn't do the subsetting properly.

```
head(occ)
  Var1 Freq tps       freqr
1   A1   74  Av 0.069418386
2  A1^    8  Av 0.007504690
3 A1^^    4  Av 0.003752345


friedman.test(data = occ,freqr~tps|Var1)

    Friedman rank sum test

data:  freqr and tps and Var1
Friedman chi-squared = 4.9231, df = 1, p-value = 0.0265

> occ2=occ[grep("^",fixed=TRUE, x=occ$Var1),]

head(occ2)
   Var1 Freq tps        freqr
2   A1^    8  Av 0.0075046904
3  A1^^    4  Av 0.0037523452
6   A2^   12  Av 0.0112570356

> friedman.test(data = occhaut,freqr~tps|Var1)

Error in friedman.test.default(c(0.0075046904315197, 0.00375234521575985,  : 
  not an unreplicated complete block design
```

Comment: Does `occ2$Var1` have only unique rows? A block desig, from the `?friedman.test` says is, "(i.e., there is exactly one observation in y for each combination of levels of groups and blocks)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, each combination of var1 and time (tps) has a unique value of frequence, that is why I don't understand why it doesn't work